# Managing multiple related lists and lookups in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, list, lookup-column

I have a custom solution, which has multiple related lists. Four of the Lists have a lookup field based on the field of one list. And, that list has a lookup based on the field of another list.

So, if the user deletes one list. It will break the functionality. How to stop the user from deleting those lists?

And, also if the user modifies the field value which is being looked up in other lists. How best to reflect the change in all the other lists.

Looking forward to your replies :)

Answer (score 1):

Give users read permissions to the lists so that the values can be read when creating list items. Only give a select few people contribute and full control.

Edits to the lookup values will get replicated to all items holding those values. It's one of the nice features of lookup columns.

Comment: Thanks Eric, unfortunately I do not have control over who has access to the site. It is an internal portal and a lot of individuals have full control access :)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change permissions, I am afraid there's not much you can do.

This is "fixed" in SharePoint 2010, with additional options that retrict deletes on the lookup list.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the users that deleting or modifying those lists puts them in an "unsupported state", then refuse to support them.

It may sound counter-intuitive, but establishing this expectation among your users will pay off in the long run.